# Find last filled row in excel using Golang

Tags: excel, go

I am looking for a way to get the last filled row in excel I.e

```
1. Lorem Ipsum
2. qui dolorem ipsum
 .
 .
nth.architecto beatae vitae <- this is the last filled row, how do I get its
number?
```

I am using the [xlsx library](https://godoc.org/github.com/tealeg/xlsx) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [example of the README](https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx#reading-xlsx-files)

```
for _, sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {
    for _, row := range sheet.Rows {
        for _, cell := range row.Cells {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", cell.String())
        }
    }
}
```

Those _ are actually indexes for the loop, which are here ignored (hence the placeholder '`_`')

But nothing prevents you to use those indexes for the row part of those loops:

```
for _, sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {
    rmax := 0
    for r, row := range sheet.Rows {
        for _, cell := range row.Cells {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", cell.String())
            // If at least one cell in this row is not empty,
            // memorize current row index
            if cell.String() != "" {
                rmax = r
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Last line: %d\n", rmax)
}
```

Comment: You could also not use `range` here and instead do a normal for loop starting at the end and going forwards looking for the first non-empty row (this way you don't waste tons of time looking at already filled in rows).